# Various run-time errors with copy/paste macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have put together a copy/paste macro that will copy selected cells from a series of workbooks in a specified path. The code will copy all rows that contain certain values (words) from all of the workbooks in the path, and pastes them in order to whatever workbook you have open in the next empty row.

Currently the code appears to be doing everything correct except for the pasting part. I am not sure why, but I am getting a "Run-time error '2147221080 (800401a8)' Automation error" **When I run the code, it does one copy and paste, and then appears to get caught in an infinite loop that must be broken. If I try to run the code again, the Run-time error appears.** The error line is commented in the code.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyRange()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wkbDest As Workbook
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Dim strExtension As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim a As Integer

    Const strPath As String = "H:\My Documents\FinalCopyPaste\"
    ChDir strPath
    strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")
    Do While strExtension <> ""
        Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
        With wkbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")
            a = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 1 To a
                If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "PIZZA" And .Cells(i, 4).Value = "WATER" And .Cells(i, 8).Value = "9/26/2019" Then
                    LastRow = wkbDest.Worksheets("Zone").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
                    'Error occurs in line below
                    .Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy wkbDest.Worksheets("Zone").Range("A" & LastRow) 'Error occurring at this line
                    .Close savechanges:=False
                End If
            Next
        End With
        strExtension = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lines

```
With wkbSource
    a = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

are just saying "Cells in the workbook"

you need to specify the worksheet too e.g.

```
With wkbSource.sheets(1)
    a = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

You also needed to specify the worksheet on the `Rows.count`

and finally your workbook close event won't work anymore within the `With` because the `With` is now referring to a worksheet PLUS it was inside the `For` loop anyway so it would've closed on the first copying instance, instead of completing the loop, so I moved it to the end (unless that was intended but I moved it anyway so I could tell the workbook to close outside the `With workbook.worksheet` clause

The whole rectified code is here:

```
Sub CopyRange()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wkbDest As Workbook
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Dim strExtension As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim a As Integer

    Const strPath As String = "H:\My Documents\FinalCopyPaste\"
    ChDir strPath
    strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")
    Do While strExtension <> ""
        Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
        With wkbSource.Sheets(1) ' I'm telling it to use the sourceworkbook, sheet 1
            a = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 1 To a
                If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "PIZZA" And .Cells(i, 4).Value = "WATER" And .Cells(i, 8).Value = "9/26/2019" Then
                    ' You also needed to specify the book and sheet here
                    LastRow = wkbDest.Worksheets("Zone").Cells(wkbDest.Worksheets("Zone").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy wkbDest.Worksheets("Zone").Range("A" & LastRow)
                End If
            Next
        End With
        'moved the close to outside the For loop and made sure it's closing wkbSource
        wkbSource.Close savechanges:=False
        strExtension = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a dot `.` in front of the first command: `.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy`, otherwise the workbook in your `With` block doesn't qualify the range.

Comment: Also, there are a few other missing `.` qualifiers e.g `a = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` should be `a = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` and the line containing `If Cells(i, 1).Value = "PIZZA"`

Comment: Thanks, but now I appear to be getting a "Run-time error '-2147221080 (800401a8)': Automation error. Let me try to fix those errors.

Comment: @jamheadart You're right. Every cell reference inside the `IF` condition inside the `With block` is missing qualification as well.

Comment: @Forkinator9000 Which line causes the Automation Error?

Comment: Without the qualifiers, it might work a lot of the time, it might not work at all, it might work for half of your loops then if you click elsewhere it might swap in the middle! You need to make sure everything inside a `With` clause is qualified so you GUARANTEE that your `cells(x,y).value` references e.g. are referring to the object you declared with `With`

Comment: @Forkinator9000 No, the `With` block works like this: `wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")` is the same as `With wb    .Sheets(1).Range("A1")    End With`

Comment: `.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy wkbDest.Worksheets("Zone").Range("A" & LastRow)` this line gives the automation error. But if I add `.` to the `Cells` it creates more errors.

Comment: @jamheadart `wkbDest` is `Set` at the very top, inbetween the variable and object declarations

Comment: Yup sorry I missed that and then deleted my comment... obivously not fast enough :D

Comment: This is also a problem, I think: `Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)`. As far as I see, `strExtension` already includes `strPath`, therefore doesn't need to be concatenated.

Comment: @Forkinator9000 Maybe update the question with the edited code so we can see what you're working on.

Comment: Problem is solved, thank you all. Refer to the other posted answer for the solution.